# rxjs expects union type when inner mapping switchMap

Tags: typescript, rxjs

[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6v2j2z?file=index.ts)

```
switchMap(innerHello => {
    return of(world).pipe(map(innerWorld => [innerHello, innerWorld]));
}),
map(([hello, world]) => {
  console.log('result', hello.hello, world.world);
})
```

How come, when using the `switchMap` operator, I have a warning saying that `property hello does not exist on type Hello | World`.
I return an array from the inner map so why is it expecting an union?

Comment: It seems to work in the demo link you shared

Comment: Yes it works but I have warnings (the squiggly red lines) on hello and world.

Comment: You need to specify argument types: `map(([hello, world]: [Hello, World])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inferred type of `[innerHello, innerWorld]` is `Array<Hello|World>` you cannot access properties that are not in both types.

What you can do is explicitly type your array as

```
map(([hello, world]: [Hello, World]) => {
  console.log('result', hello.hello, world.world);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, as I was saying in another comment, I thought that [Hello, World] would be inferred as such, not as [Hello|World]. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in another answer, typescript infers the type of the objects in the array as the union type `World|Hello`, so you wont be able to access *non-common properties* between the classes without using some form of *type guard*.

The answer provided by @David is fine, **but it forces you to cast the type of the array**.

Notice that this will break with no compiler warnings in the case that you change the order in which you add the objects into the array during its creation. (Eg.: `[innerHello, innerWorld]` into `[innerWorld, innerHello]`).

Another way to approach this, keeping the type checks with no type casting and ergo better compiler support, is to collect the properties into a plain object and then destructure it:

```
const helloVal: Hello = {
  hello: 'hello'
};
const worldVal: World = {
  world: 'world'
};

const source = of(helloVal).pipe(
  switchMap(hello => of(worldVal).pipe(map(world => ({ hello, world }))))
);

source.subscribe(({ hello, world }) => {
  console.log('result', hello.hello, world.world);
});
```

In this case, the types of `hello` and `world` are correctly inferred in the `subscribe` callback. **Note that in this case, you are "bounded" to the names of the properties used to create the result object, not their order**.

Working demo [in this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5bqpeu?file=index.ts)

Answer (score -1):

> I return an array from the inner map so why is it expecting an union?

That's what you explicitly told it to expect:

```
  console.log('result', hello.hello, world.world);
```

So, "access the `hello` property of the `hello` object (or: 0th element of the array), and access the `world` property of the `world` object".

Change it to `console.log('result', hello, world)`.

Comment: What do you mean? The warnings tell me that hello could be of Hello or World type, but I never explicitly said that.

Comment: It infers the types, from what `innerHello`'s type is, and from `world`'s (the one in `return of(world)`) type is.

Comment: Right, I (wrongly) thought that [Hello, World] would be inferred as such. Not [Hello|World].